# How to export content note for other users via data loader

Tags: content, notes, loader

When I export Content Notes via Data Loader I only get the records I own. How can I export ContentNotes for other users?

Here is the query:

```
Select Content, ContentSize, CreatedById, CreatedDate, FileExtension, FileType, Id, IsDeleted, IsReadOnly, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, LastViewedDate, LatestPublishedVersionId, OwnerId, SharingPrivacy, TextPreview, Title 
FROM ContentNote
```

Comment: what you want is `USING Scope allPrivate` but that isn't supported for `ContentNote`

Comment: OK that is good to know. Thank You!